How to refer to arguments of ifelse() function using strings in mutate(across())
Say I have this example data:
library(tidyverse)

colNames <- c('A', 'B')

df <- tibble(A = sample(1:1000, 20),
             A_Direction = 'Decreasing',
             B = sample(1:1000, 20),
             B_Direction = 'Increasing')

I want to change columns A and B such that if A_Direction or B_Direction is Decreasing, it's 0, and if it's increasing, it's 1. Here's what I've tried:
dfNew <- df %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = matches(paste0('^', colNames, '$')),
                .fns = ~ifelse(test = paste0(cur_column(), '_Direction')=='Decreasing',
                               yes = 0,
                               no = 1)))


But of course, it doesn't recognize the test argument because it's a string, so both columns become 1. Any ideas how I can accomplish this programmatically (the OG data has many, many more columns like this).

You already recognize why your test doesn't work, you are creating a string of the column name. You can still use that easily by doing df[[paste0(cur_column(), '_Direction')]]=="Decreasing", which will extract that column as a vector for comparison. Note: this won't work if you have a more complex pipe chain that has altered the values of your direction columns before this mutate() statement.

If you already have colNames you could do a named vector lookup:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

lookup <- setNames(str_c(colNames, "_Direction"), colNames)

df |>
  mutate(across(all_of(colNames), \(x) as.numeric(pick(all_of(lookup[[cur_column()]]))[[1]] == "Increasing")))

Or you can access within across() like:
df |>
  mutate(across(all_of(colNames), \(x) as.numeric(pick(all_of(str_glue("{cur_column()}_Direction")))[[1]] == "Increasing")))

And lastly, if your real data has more values than just Increasing/Decreasing, you can use case_match() like so, which also has a default argument:
df |>
  mutate(across(all_of(colNames), \(x) {
    case_match(
      pick(all_of(str_glue("{cur_column()}_Direction")))[[1]],
      "Increasing" ~ 1,
      "Decreasing" ~ 0
    )
  }))

Just add more values as shown (e.g. "Constant" ~ NA).

The advantage of using pick() (instead of df as I mentioned in the comments to your post) is that if you have modified your variables in your pipeline this function will retrieve the values in their current state:
# Output truncated with `slice()` 
df |> 
  mutate(A_Direction = replace(A_Direction, 1, "Increasing")) |>
  mutate(across(all_of(colNames), \(x) as.numeric(pick(all_of(str_glue("{cur_column()}_Direction")))[[1]] == "Increasing"))) |>
  slice(1:3)
#       A A_Direction     B B_Direction
#   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      
# 1     1 Increasing      1 Increasing # notice A is correct value
# 2     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
# 3     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 


Another option would be to wrap the column name aka paste0(cur_column(), "_Direction") in get.
Note: I also dropped the ifelse.
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

df %>%
  mutate(across(
    matches(paste0("^", colNames, "$")),
    ~ +(!get(paste0(cur_column(), "_Direction")) == "Decreasing")
  ))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>        A A_Direction     B B_Direction
#>    <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>      
#>  1     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  2     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  3     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  4     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  5     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  6     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  7     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  8     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  9     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 10     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 11     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 12     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 13     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 14     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 15     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 16     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 17     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 18     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 19     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 20     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing

or using pick():
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    matches(paste0("^", colNames, "$")),
    ~ +(!pick(paste0(cur_column(), "_Direction")) == "Decreasing")[[1]]
  ))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>        A A_Direction     B B_Direction
#>    <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>      
#>  1     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  2     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  3     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  4     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  5     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  6     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  7     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  8     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#>  9     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 10     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 11     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 12     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 13     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 14     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 15     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 16     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 17     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 18     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 19     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
#> 20     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing


Here is a pragmatic way to solve:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  select(1:2) |> 
  mutate(A = ifelse(A_Direction == "Decreasing", 0,1)) |> 
  bind_cols(df |> 
              select(3:4) |> 
              mutate(B = ifelse(B_Direction == "Decreasing", 0,1))
            )

A A_Direction     B B_Direction
   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      
 1     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
 2     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
 3     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
 4     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
 5     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
 6     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
 7     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
 8     1 Increasing      0 Decreasing 
 9     1 Increasing      0 Decreasing 
10     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
11     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
12     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 
13     1 Increasing      0 Decreasing 
14     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
15     1 Increasing      1 Increasing 
16     1 Increasing      1 Increasing 
17     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
18     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
19     0 Decreasing      1 Increasing 
20     0 Decreasing      0 Decreasing 

